# Use ElasticSearch Nest 5.6 to script sort by a boolean value

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, groovy, nest

I have an object that is in ElasticSearch 5.6 using Nest with the following property:

```
[Object(Name = "UserFlags")]
public List<long> UserFlags { get; set; }
```

I have a script sort that uses this field in the following way:

```
sorts.Add(new ScriptSort
{
    Type = "boolean",
    Order = SortOrder.Ascending,
    Script = new InlineScript("doc['UserFlags'].value.indexOf(userID) > -1")
    {
        Lang = "groovy",
        Params = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "userID", user.ID }
        }
    }
});
```

This script is always throwing an exception and fails to sort (it returns no results because the script has some issue).  Sorting by other properties work fine, and even other script sorts are working as expected:

```
sorts.Add(new ScriptSort
{
    Order = SortOrder.Ascending,
    Type = "number",
    Script = new InlineScript("doc['TotalGalleryCount'].value - doc['ClosedGalleryCount'].value")
});
```

What am I doing wrong?  The Nest documentation is aggravatingly sparse.

**EDIT**

If I revise the script to this:

```
sorts.Add(new ScriptSort
{
    Type = "string",
    Order = SortOrder.Ascending,
    Script = new InlineScript(string.Format("doc['UserFlags'].values.contains({0})", user.ID))
});
```

Then the script executes and I get results back.  However, in my unit tests, the sort doesn't seem to be affecting the results.  (Note there is an additional sort `sorts.Add(new SortField { Field = "Filename", Order = SortOrder.Ascending });` that occurs after the script sort.)

**Inputs**: ["c.jpg" (false), "a.jpg" (true), "b.jpg" (false), "a.jpg" (false)]

**Expected**: ["a.jpg" (false), "b.jpg" (false), "c.jpg" (false), "a.jpg" (true)]

**Actual**: ["a.jpg" (false), "a.jpg" (true), "b.jpg" (false), "c.jpg" (false)]

It's almost as if it is applying the sorts in the wrong order, but they are added like this:

```
sorts.Add(new ScriptSort
{
    Type = "string",
    Order = SortOrder.Ascending,
    Script = new InlineScript(string.Format("doc['UserFlags'].values.contains({0})", user.ID))
});
sorts.Add(new SortField { Field = "Filename", Order = SortOrder.Ascending });
```

Which should execute them correctly...

Comment: What is the exception the script is always throwing?

Comment: I think you want `doc['UserFlags'].values.indexOf(userID) > -1` with Groovy on a doc value field with multiple values: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/modules-scripting-groovy.html#_doc_value_properties_and_methods

Answer (score 0):

So after switching from groovy to painless, and trying a bunch of the built-in painless functions (that did not work), my final solution was this:

```
//HACK: Yes, this is ugly, but painless does not like the contains() or indexOf() functions
var script = "for (int i = 0; i < doc['UserFlags'].values.length; i++) if (doc['UserFlags'].values[i] == {0}) return true; return false;";
script = string.Format(script, user.ID);

sorts.Add(new ScriptSort
{
    Type = "string",
    Order = defaultOrder,
    Script = new InlineScript(script)
});
sorts.Add(new SortField { Field = "Filename", Order = determinedOrder });
```

We used painless instead of groovy because our servers are not allowing groovy scripting.